# Merging 2 datasets with timestamp as unique identifiers (but they are not the same)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, historian

I have 2 historian tag data. I do openquery to get these data in table. The data is like this:

TAG1:

```
timestamp1 string1
```

TAG2:

```
timestamp2 string2
```

I would like to combine this into one table

```
timestamp1 string1 string2
```

The problem is that Timestamp1 and Timestamp2 does not match. I need to get string1 and string2 together in table. Is there any option to solve this issue? Also the difference in timestamps can differ in circumstances. (it can be 100ms to 5sec)

Example:

Tag1 table:

```
   10/09/2018 22:05:00          "hello"

   10/09/2018 22:10:00          "heyhey"
```

Tag2 table:

```
  10/09/2018 22:05:28          "azeryy"

  10/09/2018 22:10:04          "qwerty"
```

Result table:

```
  10/09/2018 22:05:00          "hello"      "azeryy"

  10/09/2018 22:10:00          "heyhey"     "qwerty"
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: @sgeddes is correct, this would give you a better chances of an answer.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Timestamp is a datatype which has nothing to do with the time of day. And strings are strings, not datetime. Let's assume these are datetime, how do you want the join to work? If the values are not the same how are you going to decide which row belongs to which?

Comment: @seanLange That's exactly the question!

Comment: I can hack this together using a number of approaches. But how could you possibly be sure that any two rows belong together? If you don't care about absolute precision (and I hope you don't because this isn't possible) probably the easiest is to use ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future it would be helpful if you can post sample data. Since you are new around here I put this together for you so you can see an example of this.

```
declare @Tag1 table
(
    SomeDate datetime
    , SomeValue varchar(20)
)

insert @Tag1 values
('10/09/2018 22:05:00', 'hello')
, ('10/09/2018 22:10:00', 'heyhey')

declare @Tag2 table
(
    SomeDate datetime
    , SomeValue varchar(20)
)

insert @Tag2 values
('10/09/2018 22:05:28', 'azeryy')
, ('10/09/2018 22:10:04', 'qwerty')
```

Now we can focus on the task at hand which is very loosely merging this together. Row_Number is very helpful for this. You can read more about ROW_NUMBER here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
select t1.SomeDate
    , t1.SomeValue
    , t2.SomeValue
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by SomeDate desc)
    from @Tag1
) t1
join
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by SomeDate desc)
    from @Tag2
) t2 on t2.RowNum = t1.RowNum
order by t1.SomeDate
```